# Entity's List is not serializing using JPA in JAX-RS despite trying a million ideas from the Internet

Tags: json, jpa, jaxb, jackson, jax-rs

I have a simple JAX-RS 2 web service that contains a Customer entity, and the Customer may have zero or more Address entities associated with it.  In our service's findAll() method, we want to just return the data in each Customer, without serializeing the Addresses.  This is working perfectly.

In our find(long id) method, we want to return a specific customer with all of is Addresses.  I have tried a million things, but cannot seem to get a Customer to serialize its Addresses.  When I look in the debugger at the entity that is found by find() (code follows), it shows the List addressList as "(IndirectList) "size = 3", so I expected that the entire entity and list will be serialized, but it doesn't happen.  We do have a writer interceptor (code follows) that is used to satisfy some specific requirements.  In it, I call proceed(), so the entity is serialized by Jackson.  After serialization, I look at the json string, and it only serialized the Customer... No addresses.  I figured that I might need to force the loading of the addresses before serialization, so I called the getAddressList() method on the entity before proceed(), but it didn't help.

I am totally at a loss as to what I am doing wrong...  I really would appreciate your help with this issue.

Thank you for your time and suggestions,

Mike

```
====================================================================
=========================== TECHNOLOGIES ===========================
====================================================================
NetBeans IDE 8.0 (Build 201403101706)
Java 1.8.0_11; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.11-b03
JPA2.1
JAX2
Jackson Json 2.4.2
GlassFish Server 4
MySQL Community Server 5.6.20 (ENGINE=InnoDB)
====================================================================

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CUSTOMER CLASS
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
@XmlRootElement

public class Customer implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @XmlAttribute(required=true)
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "customerId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Address> addressList;

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Address> getAddressList() {
        return addressList;
    }

    public void setAddressList(List<Address> addressList) {
        this.addressList = addressList;
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////
// FIND A CUSTOMER BY ID
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Query to find an entity by id.
    protected T find(Object id) {                   
        // Find the object      

        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery<T> cq = cb.createQuery(entityClass);
        javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> from = cq.from(entityClass);        
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery<T> select = cq.select(from);      
        cq.where(cb.equal(from.<T>get("id"), id));

        javax.persistence.TypedQuery<T> tq = getEntityManager().createQuery(select);           

        return getSingleResultOrNull(tq); 
    }

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// WRITER INTERCEPTOR
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

@Provider
public class MyWriterInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context) 
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        final OutputStream originalStream = context.getOutputStream();        
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        context.setOutputStream(baos);       

        try
        {
            // FORCE THE ADDRESS LIST TO LOAD BEFORE SERIALIZATION?
            // IN THE DEBUGGER IT SHOWS DATA WITH "(IndirectList) "size = 3"
            // THIS FORCING DID NOT MAKE THE COLLECTION SERIALIZE TO JSON.
            Object entity = context.getEntity();
            Customer customer = (Customer) entity;

            // Force lazy load to be loaded.
            customer.getAddressList().size();

            context.proceed();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getCause());
        }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Doing a scan of the generated json to meet some specific requirements...
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        // Write to and restore the original Stream.
        baos.writeTo(originalStream);
        baos.close();
        context.setOutputStream(originalStream);
    }
```

Comment: Any reason you're using `@XmlTransient` on your addresses?

Comment: Hi John, Thank you for your response!  As I understand it, @XmlTransient is used to tell the serializer not to include an item until it has been accessed.  When it is applied to the getter(), it means that the data will be serialized when the getter() is used.  Does this help? :)  In my posting, I show that I used the getter(), but still the Addresses were not serialized.  I have gone round and round and simply am stumped after 2-days of wrestling and debugging...  Hopefully, I can get some fresh ideas here. :)

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Your understanding of `@XmlTransient` is wrong.  Can you remove it and try your example again?

Comment: Hi John, I removed the @XmlTransiet from the getAddressList() method and rebuilt/redeployed.  I had the same results as before... :(  I'd appreciate any other ideas. :)  Thank you!

Comment: Ok - I misread  your question.  You're using JSON or XML?  How are you using Jackson2? Did you register a custom `MessageBodyWriter`?  Looks like GlassFish ships with Jackson 1.9.x

Comment: Hi John,  Our application only requires json.  We are using Jackson Json 2.4.2.  Jackson has its own provider, which we are using.  Here are the technologies that we are using:

Comment: ====================================================================
=========================== TECHNOLOGIES ===========================
====================================================================
NetBeans IDE 8.0 (Build 201403101706)
Java 1.8.0_11; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.11-b03
JPA2.1
JAX2
Jackson Json 2.4.2
GlassFish Server 4
MySQL Community Server 5.6.20 (ENGINE=InnoDB)
====================================================================

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60469/discussion-between-a-bit-of-help-and-john-ament).

Comment: have you tried to use Response and wrap the response list using `GenericEntity`? Something like: `List<?> list = new ArrayList<?>();  GenericEntity<List<?>> entity = new GenericEntity<List<?>>(list) {};  return Response.status(Status.OK) .entity(entity).build();   `